# Istio AuthorizationPolicy rules questions

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I’ve been testing istio (1.6) authorization policies and would like to confirm the following:

1. Can I use k8s service names as shown below where `httpbin.bar` is the service name for deployment/workload httpbin:

```
   - to:
     - operation:
         hosts: ["httpbin.bar"]
```

2. I have the following rule; only ALLOW access to the `httpbin.bar` service from service account `sleep` in `foo` namespace.

```
---
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: whitelist-httpbin-bar
  namespace: bar
  action: ALLOW 
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
        principals: ["cluster.local/ns/foo/sa/sleep"]
  - to:
    - operation:
        hosts: ["httpbin.bar"]
```

I setup 2 services; `httpbin.bar` and `privatehttpbin.bar`. My assumption was that it would block access to `privatehttpbin.bar` but this is not the case. On a side note, I deliberately avoided adding `selector.matchLabels` because as far as I can tell the rule should only succeed for `httpbin.bar`.

The docs state:

> A match occurs when at least one source, operation and condition matches the request.

as per [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/#Rule).

I interpreted that AND logic will apply to the `source` and `operation`.

Would appreciate if I can find out why this may not be working or if my understanding needs to be corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your `AuthorizationPolicy` object, you have two rules in the namespace bar:

- Allow any request coming from `foo` namespace; with service account `sleep` to any service.
- Allow any request to `httpbin` service; from any namespace, with any service account.

So it is an OR, you are applying.

If you want and AND to be applied; meaning allow any request from the namespace `foo` with service account `sleep` to talk to the service `httpbin`, in the namespace bar, you need to apply the following rule:

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: whitelist-httpbin-bar
  namespace: bar
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
        principals: ["cluster.local/ns/foo/sa/sleep"]
    to:                     # <- remove the dash (-) from here
    - operation:
        hosts: ["httpbin.bar"]
```

Comment: That was a nice find.

Comment: hmm seemed like it should have worked but it doesn't. unless it does but `hosts: ["httpbin.bar"]` is not honoured so it always fails. I also failed to add the `action: ALLOW` to my original question which I have updated now.

Comment: @sachin I had the same problem. Istio team helped me out, and it started working for me

Comment: @kaizenCoder you will need to make the request explicitly to `httpbin.bar` or pass host header. If you'd do the request from the same namespace to `httpbin`, it would fail.

Comment: Yup that's right, I'm using the istio examples to simulate this by running:

`kubectl exec "$(kubectl get pod -l app=sleep -n foo -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name})" -c sleep -n foo -- curl http://httpbin.bar:8000/ip -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n"`

Comment: So turns out it respects the `Host` header but it needs the port included e.g: `hosts: ["httpbin.bar:8000"]`.

Answer (score 1):

On the first point You can specify the host name by k8s service name.Therefore httpbin.bar is acceptable for the host field.

On the second point,
As per [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/) ,

> Authorization Policy scope (target) is determined by
>   “metadata/namespace” and an optional “selector”.
>
> “metadata/namespace” tells which namespace the policy applies. If set
>   to root namespace, the policy applies to all namespaces in a mesh.

So the authorization policy `whitelist-httpbin-bar` applies to workloads in the namespace `foo`.But the services `httpbin` and `privatehttpbin` you want to authorize lies in `bar` namespace.So your authorization policy does not restrict access to these services.

> If there are no ALLOW policies for the workload, allow the request.

The above criteria makes the request a valid one.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Q1. On Q2, The namespace is actually `bar`. I incorrectly added it here as `foo` (I updated the question). If i'm going by what you are saying it should work however I can only seem to get it to work if I add `selector.matchLabels` to match the `httbin` workload at which point it blocks `privatehttpbin`.

Comment: @kaizenCoder sorry I might be wrong on the first point.The host field can take k8s values in other resources but I don't know if its accepted in the authorization policy.

Comment: I think you have to specify the workload selector for the use case.